# Django NoReverseMatch while return render()

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I always receive a `NoReverseMatch` error, and I don't know why.
This is the error message:

> NoReverseMatch at /suche/any-thing/
>
> Reverse for 'article_search' with arguments '(u'any thing',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['suche/(?P[-\w]+)/$']

So as you can see, I'm entering a url with "-" instead of whitespace, but Django is looking for url pattern with the space instead of "-".

This is my url pattern:

```
    url(r'suche/(?P<search>[-\w]+)/$', views.article_search_view, name='article_search'),
```

Surprisingly Django starts to compute my article_search_view, which looks like this:

```
def article_search_view(request, search=None):
"""Filters all articles depending on the search and renders them"""

articles = get_active_not_rented_articles()
search = re.sub(r"[-]", ' ', search)
articles = articles.filter(title__icontains=search)
articles = aply_sort(request, articles)
orderd_by = articles[0].get('filter')
articles = articles[1]
return render(request, 'article/list.html', {'object_list':articles, 'url_origin':'article_search', 'parameter':search,
'orderd_by':orderd_by})
```

As I checked with "print()" statements, the error is raised when the return render(...) statement is called.
If I do a return redirect(...) instead, no error will be raised.
For completeness, my article/list.html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div id =articles>
<div class="info_filter">
<div class="header_info_filter">
  {% if orderd_by == "not" %}
  <h1>Neueste Artikel</h1>
  {% endif %}
  {% if orderd_by == "distance" %}
  <h1>Artikel in Ihrer Nähe</h1>
  {% endif %}
  {% if orderd_by == "price_asc" %}
  <h1>Günstigste Artikel zuerst</h1>
  {% endif %}
  {% if orderd_by == "price_des" %}
  <h1>Teuerste Artikel zuerst</h1>
  {% endif %}
</div>

<div class="selection">
  {% if parameter1 %}
  <form action="{% url url_origin parameter1 parameter2 %}" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    {% else %}
    {% if parameter %}
    <form action="{% url url_origin parameter %}" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
      {% else %}
      <form action="{% url url_origin %}" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="select_filter">
          <select name="filter" id="filter" >
            <option value="distance">Entfernung</option>
            <option value="price_asc">Preis, aufsteigend</option>
            <option value="price_des">Preis, absteigend</option>
          </select>
          <div class="search_filter_btn">
            <button type="submit" name="button">Sortieren</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
    {% if parent_categorys %}
    <div class="category-path">
      Ergebnisse für:
      {% for category in parent_categorys %}
      <a href="{% url 'article_category' category.slug %}"> > {{ category.name }}</a>
      {% endfor %}
      {% if parameter2 %}
      : {{ parameter2}}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% else %}
    Ergebnisse für: {{ parameter}}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  <div id="main" class="article_list">
    {% for article in object_list %}
    <div class="item">
      <div class="list_img">
        <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}">
          <img src="{% if article.main_picture %}{{ article.main_picture.url }}{% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">
        </a>

      </div>
      <div class= "articles_fee" >
        {{ article.fee }} €
      </div>
      <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}">{{ article.title }}</a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I can't understand what those parameters are or why you're attempting to send them in the URL, rather than in the posted form data.

Comment: try and change the regex to be: `r'suche/(?P<search>[\w\-]+)/$'` see if that works

Comment: N. Ivanov: i tryed it, but i does not solve the probleme, same error
Daniel Rosemann: because is want comprehensibly urls

Comment: The problem is coming from your template. The `url`s that you are building are causing the unresolved references. Try remove the code with urls (`{% url 'article_category' category.slug %}`, and all the `action=` on the forms in list.html) and see if the problem still persists. I believe that is causing django to crash, but why on the other hand I am not sure. I am guessing that 1 or more of the links are bad. Hope this helps!

Comment: The template works fine for all other calls "/suche/hhhhh/" ore many others, so i dont think those hrefs are the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, you change `search` and replace hyphens with spaces. This causes an error when you use the url tag in your template, because the URL pattern does not allow spaces.

```
{% url url_origin parameter %}
```

You could fix the problem by adding the original search slug to the template context:

```
def article_search_view(request, search=None):
    """Filters all articles depending on the search and renders them"""
    search_slug = search
    articles = get_active_not_rented_articles()
    search = re.sub(r"[-]", ' ', search)
    ...
    return render(request, 'article/list.html', {'object_list':articles, 'url_origin':'article_search', 'parameter':search, 'search_slug': search_slug, 'orderd_by':orderd_by})
```

Then change the url tag:

```
{% url url_origin search_slug %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, thats the solution!